# Update selected columns in 2D numpy array with 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

Given the following arrays:

```
from numpy import * 
b = ones((5,5))
a = arange(4)
```

How do I get the following array with minimum amount of code? Basically update parts of array `b` with array `a`:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

In matlab I can use one line to achieve this:

```
b = ones(5,5);
a = [0,1,2,3];
b(1:4,2:4) = repmat(a',[1,3])
```

Comment: Indexing with slices (`:`) is basically the same in MATLAB and numpy.  There are differences, though, when indexing with lists. `b[[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` is different (and will produce an error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
b[0:4, 1:4] = a[:, None]
```

Which makes `b` equal to:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

`b[0:4, 1:4]` selects the appropriate slice of `b` (recall that Python uses zero-based indexing).

To complete the assignment of the vector `a`, it is necessary to add an extra axis of length 1 using `a[:, None]`. This is because the slice of `b` has shape (4, 3) and we need `a` to have shape (4, 1) so that the axes line up correctly to allow broadcasting.

Comment: That `[:, None]` is simpler than the MATLAB `repmat`.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize output array and set `a`, just like we did for MATLAB -

```
b = np.ones((5,5))
a = np.array([0,1,2,3])
```

Now, let's use the automatic broadcasting supported by NumPy to replace the explicit replication done by `repmat` in MATLAB, for which we need to make `a` a 2D array by "pushing" the 1D elements along the first axis and introducing a singleton dimension as the second axis with [`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) as `a[:,np.newaxis]`. Please note the general term for dimension in NumPy is axis. A shorthand for `np.newaxis` is `None`, thus we need to use `a[:,None]` and use this for assigning elements into `b`.

Thus, the final step would be considering we have `0-based` indexing in Python, we would have -

```
b[0:4,1:4] = a[:,None]
```